# gradle dsl method not found 'compile()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, material-design, build.gradle

*I'm having trouble with build.gradle. How can I fix it?
build.gradle code here:*

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

            compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'


        }
    }
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']

            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']

            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

Comment: defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 6
        versionName '1.4'
    }
}

ext.siteUrl = 'https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary'
ext.issueUrl = 'https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues'
ext.gitUrl = 'https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary.git'

Comment: bintray {
    user = hasProperty('BINTRAY_USER') ? BINTRAY_USER : "navasmdc"
    key = hasProperty('BINTRAY_KEY') ? BINTRAY_PASSWORD : ""

    configurations = ["archives"]
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'MaterialDesignLibrary'
        desc = 'This is a library with components of Android L to you use in android 2.2'
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        issueTrackerUrl = issueUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        labels = []
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}

Comment: install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                name 'MaterialDesignLibrary'
                url siteUrl
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }

Comment: developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'navasmdc'
                        name 'Iván Navas'
                        email 'i.navas.mdc@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Comment: task findConventions << {
    println project.getConvention()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'


    }
}

Comment: Its difficult to understand .please post this in your question

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
  compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
```

from the `buildscript` block.

Then add the dependency in the dependency block (outside the buildscript):

```
dependencies { 
   compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+' 
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+' 
   compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
}
```

It requires that you have to add outside the buildscript block.

```
repositories {
       jcenter()
}
```

Also, since you are using the `com.github.dcendents.android-maven` plugin you have to change the `buildscript` block.
Check [here](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) for more info:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: when i remove it i have this error :  plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found

Comment: @SassiMedAmine It is another issue. Anyway I've updated the answer.

Comment: thnx a lot it work.                                                                                      but after adding classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3'  i had this error : failed to resolve : com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+

Comment: @SassiMedAmine add in your build.gradle repositories {
            jcenter()
        }. Updated the answer.

Comment: it works fine . but in the message area i have this error    : Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.gc.materialdesign'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Comment: No. Post your entire build.gradle. it is very difficult to read the initial comments.

Comment: im having issues when i try to post the whole gradle .can you please give me your email and i'll send  it to you.?

Comment: Not sure about it. Are you using in the project another module/app with the same package in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: @SassiMedAmine In any case you should open a new question on SO.It is another issue and other user can help you with a new topic.. If the answer resolves the issue on topic mark the answer as it can help other users.